# SQL Update of MD5 Passwords with plain text

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update my records.  I want to change our plaintext passwords into MD5 encoded passwords.  This is what I tried to use:

```
UPDATE testing SET password = MD5('Manojano234')
```

This query was working for the string I put in there, but I need to be encoding the password and not just that one string

Comment: Maybe you mean `UPDATE testing SET password = MD5(password)`?

Comment: no i mean that UPDATE testing SET password = MD5(password) + md5(my plain text) ... sorry i dont know how to write in sql...

Comment: returns an MD5 + sum of $plain  our secret word

Comment: I hope you're not using this in any kind of publicly accessible system. Simple MD5 for passwords is just **reckless**. ;-)

Comment: One does not simply save plain text passwords on a database.

Answer (score 1):

This is really what you want to do.  Appending a MD5ed salt to and MD5ed password is not the way to go.  An attacker would see that there are two MD5ed strings concatenated together, as the last part of every password would be the same.  Appending them and **then** MD5ing is the way to go.  Use this:

```
UPDATE testing SET password = MD5(CONCAT(password, 'A Custom Salt You Pick'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write something like this:

```
UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), 'plain text')
```

Comment: So, I misunderstood your problem. Can you give an example?

Comment: first criteria->md5  encrypted my db password value second criteria->md5 into my plain text secret word value third criteria->result should be combined encrypted password plus my secret word md5 encryption

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query like :

```
UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), MD5('Your plain text')) WHERE "Need to write your condition to update this record"
```

Comment: thanks for your appreciation guyss... i can using concat function the encypted md5 is generated in md5 password and also plain text ... the result was that query like that 5553c89656bb06cc71d93ff81a8a929bca2457f7542bbc44c6...  but i need to return and combine MD5 and  $plain text our secret word

Comment: Can you please specify it more clearly because I am not getting you exactly what you want to do

Comment: okay i need to explain with example ... i was running your query ...UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), MD5('xyz123')) the result was not together ...it shows md5(password)->xxxyyyzzzzz like that and MD5('xyz123'))->yyyyzzzooppp ..so it should be show both combined xxxyyyzzzzyyyyzzzooppp...

Comment: Yes I have try my query on my database and it is giving me the same result as you expected

Comment: wait i ll review at one time

Comment: i can add new user and set password it should be generated 32 bit characters (ie) md5(mano:myplaintext) result was f346241c21fed293dbe57dcc28fa4a1e 32 bit of characters ...but i can update in my sql query password should be generated 64 bit characters (ie)  f346241c21fed293dbe57dcc28fa4a1ef346241c21fed293dbe57dcc28fa4a1e  ...

Comment: 32 bit 64 bit its not a problem suppose login panel it should be work na i can also change database password field character ... but i can change these way my login panel not working .... but i can run in my php and change password it should be working fine ...i come with sql query doesnt work

Comment: when I will do md5 for '123456' then it is : e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
Now when I will do md5 for 'test' then it is : 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6

Now in your case what you required you want to concat both and it should be : 

e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6

or you want to concat it but it should product only 32 bit string so it will be :

md5('123456 test') and it will product 32 bit string only

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to convert your plain text passwords into MD5 passwords.  I am also **appending** a salt.

```
UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), MD5('plain text'))
```

Comment: Pardon, I dint get what you mean to say could you please tell with an example what is the input value and its desired output

Comment: okay i need to explain with example ... i was running your query ...UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), MD5('xyz123'))  the result was not together ...it shows md5(password)->xxxyyyzzzzz like that and   MD5('xyz123'))->yyyyzzzooppp ..so it should be show both combined xxxyyyzzzzyyyyzzzooppp...

Comment: Yes it would be easy to understand

Comment: UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), MD5('xyz123')) the result was not together ...it shows md5(password)->xxxyyyzzzzz like that and MD5('xyz123'))->yyyyzzzooppp ..so it should be show both combined xxxyyyzzzzyyyyzzzooppp..

Comment: function StandardHash($plain) {
 # returns an MD5 sum of $plain plus our secret word
 # NEVER _EVER_ CHANGE THE SECRET WORD.
 //return md5("$plain:AtogVoj7");
 return md5("$plain:MANoj");
}    $_REQUEST['eng_logpwd']=StandardHash($_REQUEST['eng_logpwd']);   this is for my php script ....i need to these changes in my mysql query...

Comment: For your case the query UPDATE testing SET password = CONCAT(MD5(password), MD5('xyz123')) produces correct result in my side say I have a password = 123 so its md5 would be 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 and plain text = sometext and its respective md5 = a29e90948f4eee52168fab5fa9cfbcf8 and from the above query you would definitely get 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70a29e90948f4eee52168fab5fa9cfbcf8 so what is the issue

Comment: yeah you are right but in php coding i can add new user and set password it should be generated 32 bit characters (ie) md5(mano:myplaintext) result was f346241c21fed293dbe57dcc28fa4a1e 32 bit of characters ...but i can update in my sql query password should be generated 64 bit characters (ie) f346241c21fed293dbe57dcc28fa4a1ef346241c21fed293dbe57dcc28fa4a1e

Comment: 32 bit 64 bit its not a problem suppose login panel it should be work na i can also change database password field character  ... but i can change these way my login panel not working .... but i can run in my php and change password it should be working fine ...i come with sql query doesnt work

Comment: Do you men to say after updating the password in database you are not able to login through the system

Comment: yeah after updating my password in my database i was not able to login

Comment: In that case while checking if user exist or not you must be executing the query like select user where username = my user and password = MD5(password) update this to select user where username = my user and password Like MD5(password)%

Comment: nope i check and clearly user doesn't exists ... my problem was md5 encryption is differ from my php script and database query ...for example i add new user through php script password is generating fine and working fine also but i can do it sql queries password generation is wrong and user password is wrong and not to login furthermore...